# Embed facebook post & insert dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook

I want to embed a bunch of Facebook posts ([Embed fb post](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-posts)) dynamically.

I tried using `jQuery.append()`...

```
$("body").append('<div class="fb-post" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/FacebookDevelopers/posts/10152128760693553" data-width="500"></div>');
```

But it didn't worked as expected.

Comment: Explain _"didn't worked as expected"_ in more detail.

Comment: didn't worked at all :(

Comment: The `div` wasn't appended? The Facebook post didn't load? Your computer turned in to a cat? You need to be more specific.

Comment: dude it worked fine at last!!, thank you for your response `<div id='my_id'><fb:post href='post_url'></fb:post></div>" and called the FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById('my_id')) `